# NuGet Issues - Updating a package breaks build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I am going to lose my mind. NuGet has decided that any attempt to update a package destroys my Solution. I am running Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate w/ Update 3. I have been working on this solution/application for over a year and had no troubles. This weekend NuGet started breaking my solution build every time I update a package, regardless of what package I update. Say, for example, I update AutoMapper. It tells me that it updates successfully but when I build it fails to find the assembly/reference. I then start having problems with all of the other NuGet Package references. I sometimes get errors that there are syntax errors with MsBuild, target framework version errors, etc. I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2013, uninstalling resharper, reinstalling resharper, clearing NuGet cache, Visual Studio 2013 component cache. I am out of ideas short of rebuilding my machine.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE: 09/02/2014

I tried this process on a brand new machine and I got a lot further. I still, however, do have the following problem with my build. This problem seems to happen on every machine.

Error   4   Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[MSBuild]::MakeRelative($(MSBuildProjectDirectory), C:...\Source\packages\AutoMapper.3.2.1\lib\net40\AutoMapper.Net4.dll)". Method '[MSBuild]::MakeRelative' not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)).    ChoiceMentor.Presentation.Services

Comment: Have you performed a diff between what works and what doesn't? This will help narrow down what NuGet is doing to your project.

Comment: Good idea. I'll download Beyond Compare after this next release and give it a shot.

Comment: After your update the problem look like in changes in csproj or build command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the answer was that a comma had been put into one of the file path folder names. This caused MSBuild to throw a huge fit. Renaming the folder fixed the issue. Thanks for the tips though everyone!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Which folders are you referring to?

Comment: It was a user created folder in my situation pulled in through GitHub merging. It was a user error, not a technology error, in my case.

Comment: In my case it was changing the Build name